# If DROP in iptables returns no error to host, why ping gets error message "sendmsg: Operation not permitted"?

Tags: networking, tcp, iptables

I want my OS drops network packages silently, without awareness of application. I set following rules:

```
# iptables -N NEW_CHAIN 
# iptables -A OUTPUT -d 10.211.55.6 -j NEW_CHAIN
# iptables -A NEW_CHAIN -j DROP
```

Then I issues ping and get following errors:

```
# ping 10.211.55.6
PING 10.211.55.6 (10.211.55.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

If I delete the iptables rules, ping works fine.

My question is: since the man page of iptables says DROP will return no error to host, why there is a "Operation not permitted" error there?